# React Parent Component's this.state is called after Child Component''s constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-state

I'm encountering some counterintuitive behavior in react (at least to me). I have an API call that returns some JSON to be displayed. I wanted the result of this call to be in the state of a Parent Component('Problem Container'), and passed down as props to its child component ('Problem').

I was getting an undefined result in the child component so I did some console logging in 4 different places to see what was going on: once in each constructor, and once in each components "this.state" using my "getProblemsFromAPI()" function.

The Parent Component:

```
class ProblemContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state =  {
      problem_set: getProblemsFromAPI()
    };
    {console.log(this.state.problem_set, 'parent constructor')}
  }


  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <Problem problem_set={this.problem_set} />
      </div>
    )
  }

}

function getProblemsFromAPI(problem_set = {}) {
  fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/problem_set/5")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {console.log(data, 'set state of parent'); return data});
  }
```

The Child Component:

```
class Problem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      current_problem: '',
      problem_set: getProblemsFromAPI()
    }
    console.log(this.props, 'child constructor')
  }


    render() {
        return (
          <div>

          </div>
        );
      }

    }

function getProblemsFromAPI(problem_set = {}) {
  fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/problem_set/5")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {console.log(data, 'set state of child'); return data});
  }
```

What I'm seeing in the console is:

1. "Parent Constructor"
2. "Child Constructor"
3. "Set State of Parent"
4. "Set State of Child"

This is weird to me because the "this.state" constructor of the Parent Component should be the first thing sequentially called. I can put the API call in the componentDidMount of the child component to move forward, that's not an issue. I just don't understand this behavior.

Is this happening because it's a function call and not a value? I'm new to both javascript and react. Any advice will help!

Thanks

Comment: `Parent Component should be the first thing sequentially called`...why? You are making an `async` call before you log anything in the parent. `async`

Comment: `getProblemsFromAPI` should `return fetch(...)` since it returns a Promise. Then, if you actually want to use the value. you'll either need to use `await` inside an async function, or use `getProblemsFromAPI().then(data => ...)`. Neither of these belong in the constructor of a component. It's best to do data fetching like this in `componentDidMount`, which runs after React has mounted the component into DOM. See: [AJAX and APIs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) and [Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

Comment: @Adam Well, the parent constructor was the first thing logged in the console. It appears to have skipped over this.state and logged the "Parent constructor" message. It seems natural to me for an object to be initialized with its whole state before rendering another object. But is this is obviously wrong intuition. Maybe I'm thinking like how it would work in Python which is what I'm used to?

Comment: The thing is getProblemsFromAPI is an async function and react continues to process the rest of the things and call the child constructor too which also triggers an async method.

Comment: @PeteWalker - can you post your **actual** console messages

Answer (score 0):

Any side-effects like fetching data from an external API or any state variable update should be done after the component has mounted in `componentDidMount` life cycle method if using class components or in `useEffect` hook if using functional components. Since you said you want the `ProblemContainer` to pass the data to it's children. The `ProblemContainer` should be responsible for fetching the data.

For example,

```
class ProblemContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state =  {
      problem_set: null,
      error: undefined
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
   fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/problem_set/5")
     .then(response => response.json())
     .then((data) => {this.setState({problem_set: data})});
     // never leave a promise with out catching the error
     .catch(error => {
       // you can console.log the error to see what is going wrong

       this.setState({problem_set: null, error: error})
     })
  } 




  render() {

    return(
      <div>
        <Problem problem_set={this.state.problem_set} /> // you need to pass the prop like this
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

In your problem component,

```
class Problem extends React.Component {
  // you have access to the problem_set via this.props.problem_set
    render() {
       console.log(this.props.problem_set) // should show the expected result
        return (
          <div>
             // component logic
          </div>
        );
      }

    }
```